# conflict_free/2

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a program that takes lists of packages and versions. It should be true if there are no conflicting versions, in the candidate set. That is, if there are no packages that are listed with different versions.

```
?- conflict_free([cython, gcc, gcc], ['0.11.2', '4.4.3', '4.4.3']).
true.

?- conflict_free([cython, gcc, gcc], ['0.11.2', '4.4.3', '4.4.0']).
false.

?- conflict_free([gfortran, gcc, libc6, libc6], ['4.4.3', '4.4.3', '2.11.1', '2.11.1']).
true.

?- conflict_free([gfortran, gcc, libc6, libc6], ['4.4.3', '4.4.3', '2.11.1', '2.7.3']).
false.
```

I tried to use position/4 to find the indexes of repeating elements which behaves like:

```
?- positions([a, b, c, b, c, a, d, b, c], b, Posn, 0).
Posn = [1, 3, 7].

?- positions([cython, gcc, gcc], gcc, Posn, 0).
Posn = [1, 2].
```

I tried to recursively use `position/4` to check if there the return `Posn` is >= `2`, then try to use the indexes in versions list and see if there is any different version. But that hasn't been working for me...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's `zip` the lists, combining them into a list of pairs:

```
?- pairs_keys_values(PkgVer, [cython, gcc, gcc], ['0.11.2', '4.4.3', '4.4.3']).
PkgVer = [cython-'0.11.2', gcc-'4.4.3', gcc-'4.4.3'].
```

`pairs_keys_values` is easy enough to implement if your Prolog doesn't have it. Now, get rid of the duplicate key values pairs:

```
?- pairs_keys_values(PkgVer, [cython, gcc, gcc], ['0.11.2', '4.4.3', '4.4.3']),
|    list_to_set(PkgVer, S).
PkgVer = [cython-'0.11.2', gcc-'4.4.3', gcc-'4.4.3'],
S = [cython-'0.11.2', gcc-'4.4.3'].
```

This uses the SWI-Prolog predicate `list_to_set/2`. You can also use `sort/2`. Unzip the set:

```
?- pairs_keys_values(PkgVer, [cython, gcc, gcc], ['0.11.2', '4.4.3', '4.4.3']),
|    list_to_set(PkgVer, S),
|    pairs_keys_values(S, Packages, _).
PkgVer = [cython-'0.11.2', gcc-'4.4.3', gcc-'4.4.3'],
S = [cython-'0.11.2', gcc-'4.4.3'],
Packages = [cython, gcc] .
```

Finally, you can check whether `Packages` is a set with SWI's `is_set` predicate or some reimplementation thereof (hint: `sort/2` the list, then check whether the length changes). So,

```
conflict_free(Packages, Versions) :-
    pairs_keys_values(PkgVer, Packages, Versions),
    list_to_set(PkgVer, PkgVerSet),
    pairs_keys_values(PkgVerSet, PkgSet, _),
    is_set(PkgSet).
```

Comment: zip/3 could be [pairs_keys_values](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=pairs_keys_values/3)/3...

Comment: @chac: thanks, I was looking in the wrong place for that predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple implementation:

```
conflict_free(Packages, Versions) :-
    \+ (nth1(I, Packages, P),
        nth1(I, Versions, A),
        nth1(J, Packages, P), J \= I,
        nth1(J, Versions, B), A \= B ).
```

test:

```
?- conflict_free([cython, gcc, gcc], ['0.11.2', '4.4.3', '4.4.3']).
true.

?- conflict_free([cython, gcc, gcc], ['0.11.2', '4.4.3', '4.4.0']).
false.

?- conflict_free([gfortran, gcc, libc6, libc6], ['4.4.3', '4.4.3', '2.11.1', '2.11.1']).
true.

?- conflict_free([gfortran, gcc, libc6, libc6], ['4.4.3', '4.4.3', '2.11.1', '2.7.3']).
false.
```

nth1/3 it's used to pair a Package with a Version at Position, thus the rule can read:

> there are no packages that are listed with different versions

Comment: This version is shorter than mine, but runs in quadratic time.

Comment: Yes, the test is repeated with I and J swapped. Simplicity has some additional cost here....

Comment: That's not the point. Even if you skip the pairs `I`, `J` where `J >= I`, you still loop n*(n-1)/2 = O(n²) times. My version can run in O(n lg n) or even O(n) time depending on how `list_to_set` and `is_set` are implemented.